# Nhibernate QueryOver use alias in Eager Fetch

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

I'm trying to get nhibernate to use a alias in a eager fetch. Im not sure its possible.

I'm trying to use the alias (bAlias in my example) in my fetch.

```
QueryOver<A>() 
.JoinAlias(x => x.B, () => bAlias) 
.JoinAlias(x => x.B, () => bAlias2) 
.Where(() => bAlias2.Surname == "Smith") 
.Fetch(() => bAlias).Eager 
.Fetch(() => bAlias.C).Eager;
```

As you can see the fetch commands are using the 2 alias's instead of the direct path from .

The above code doesn't work. The code that does work is

```
QueryOver<A>() 
.JoinAlias(x => x.B, () => bAlias) 
.JoinAlias(x => x.B, () => bAlias2) 
.Where(() => bAlias2.Surname == "Smith") 
.Fetch(x => x.B).Eager 
.Fetch(x => x.B.C).Eager;
```

As you can see its the Fetch statements that are different.

Comment: Why do you need to use the alias from `JoinAlias`?

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
B b = null;

QueryOver<A>()
   .Fetch(x => x.B).Eager
   .JoinAlias(x => x.B, () => b, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin);
```

Comment: Good answer. Also, here's a link to the official documentation on aliases: http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryqueryover-aliases

Comment: Sorry guys I think I need to explain in more detail what I'm trying to achieve. I'm trying to use the alias (bAlias in my example) in my fetch.

    QueryOver<A>()
    .JoinAlias(x => x.B, () => bAlias)
    .JoinAlias(x => x.B, () => bAlias2)
    .Where(() => bAlias2.Surname == "Smith")
    .Fetch(() => bAlias).Eager
    .Fetch(() => bAlias.C).Eager;

As you can see the fetch commands are using the 2 alias's instead of the direct path from <A>

Comment: @SteveParry: You should update your question giving more details then.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a join instead, `Fetch` resolves to <strike>`INNER JOIN`</strike> `LEFT OUTER JOIN` anyway.

```
QueryOver<A>() 
    .JoinAlias(x => x.B, () => bAlias) 
    .Where(() => bAlias.Surname == "Smith") 
    .Fetch(x => x.B).Eager 
    .JoinQueryOver(() => bAlias.C)
```

Comment: I guess that by "INNER JOIN" you mean "LEFT OUTER JOIN"? ;) example: https://gist.github.com/Meligy/877532